# Get 3 dates before the current date UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I know i can get today's date `$(date +%F)` in 2015-09-02 format.

I want 3 previous dates from today's date like 2015-09-01,2015-08-31 and 2015-08-30.

How can i get this . Please Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$> date '+%F'
2015-09-02
$> date '+%F' -d "1 day ago"
2015-09-01
$> date '+%F' -d "2 day ago"
2015-08-31
$> date '+%F' -d "3 day ago"
2015-08-30
```

To store them in variables use:

```
prev1=$(date '+%F' -d "1 day ago")
prev2=$(date '+%F' -d "2 day ago")
prev3=$(date '+%F' -d "3 day ago")
```

Comment: Yes the above command woking perfectly in bash. Thanks a lot . How can i get the same result in ksh ? please help

Comment: `date` command should work same in `ksh`, let me run this in `ksh` also.

Answer (score 1):

if you had gnu date, you could do:

```
date -d '-1 day' '+%F'
```

to get previous day, also you can replace the `-1` by `-2, -3, -4 ... 1, 2, 3... 200 etc`